# Error while installing tensorflow on linux

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow on linux with the steps mentioned here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile.

When I run this line- make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile , I get an error. The error is-
*** No rule to make target '/home/ahmad/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/proto/tensorflow/core/util/test_log.pb.cc', needed by '/home/ahmad/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/obj/tensorflow/core/util/test_log.pb.p. Stop

Answer (score 1):

You might want to visit the TensorFlow's website which contains exact steps to install TensorFlow:

[https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/index.html)

Just follow the Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit sections and make sure to use install the correct TF_BINARY file based on your version of python and whether or not you choose to have GPU enabled